# Get parameter values of the calling method

Tags: java, reflection, method-parameters

How to get parameter values of the calling method?

I have scenario where there are two classes viz., Class A and Class B containing two methods mthA(in Class A) and mthB(in Class B). mthA calls mthB. now I want to know in mthB that what all parameters have been passed to mthA. This is basically for logging and handling exceptions. I am able to get the class name of the calling class i.e Class A and the method name which is calling mthB i.e mthA. but I am stuck at getting the parameters of mthA.

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName()
```

this gives me the class name of the calling method i.e Class A.

```
Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName()
```

This gives me the method name of the calling method i.e mthA.

If somehow I can get the whole method itself then I can get the method parameters passed to this method by using getParameters().

Answer (score 0):

There is simplest way or is it necessary to use Reflection..?

If you want to know what parameter is passed for `mthA`  then pass same parameter to `mthB` also Ex:

```
mthA(1stParam, 2ndParam, ...){
     mthB(1stParam, 2ndParam, ..., OtherParamertsForMthB);          
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to get calling method's arguments values, (if you can not change the parameters of called method to include and pass calling parameters values).

Using some APIs like what Thread provides, we can get the static info like class/method name, but not runtime info like arguments values. One way could be to store and manage that kind of info somewhere and show when required in case of logging/exception. I dont think there's an API for that in java.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for logging purpose only, then you should log in `mthA` itself all the arguments passed into the method.

Why should `mthB` know about `mthA`'s argument values to handle exceptions? If you are doing that, then you should consider refactoring the code and handle exceptions at the appropriate levels. If values passed to `mthA` is leading to an exception, then it should be handled there itself before calling `mthB`.

Reflection only helps in getting static information of the class and methods and does not provide runtime values of the arguments passed into a method.

Comment: mthB has to re-execute methA hence mthB should know what paramters where passed to methA. In my scenario if mthA fails then i just need to re-execute that method(after sleep time) again to resolve it. hence i need to know the parameters that where passed to mthA and re-execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some AOP tool like AspectJ to capture these values and log? You can use execution() point cut along with after() advice. For non production deployment you can log all the method calls along with passed values and returned value. This will be too much overhead for production env. For that you can just store the passed values (Object args[] as you get in AspectJ advice) in local variable and only log it in case of exception. But even in that case there will be some performance penalty as primitive values will be boxed to be passed as Object[] to your advice.

Comment: Hi @Amol U i had googled on AspectJ. i think i can use that thing. but can u point me to some good easy to understand examples. wherever i've searched i found out that AspectJ could be used with Springs framework. but i am not using Spring framework. mine is a selenium webdriver framework. could u point out some examples in this context.